# Why doesn't dictionary value change accordingly in the original dict when it's modified?

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  "a": [420, 380, 390],
  "b": [50, 40, 45]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  "c": [420, 380, 390],
  "d": [50, 40, 45]
})

dfs = {'df1': df1, 'df2':df2}

for name, df in dfs.items():
    df = {}
    pass

print('dfs: ', dfs)
```

When I modify each df in the for loop, why isn't this change updated to the dfs? I suppose the print() should print an empty dict, but it didn't change at all. I have do an explicit reassignment to update dfs:

```
for name, df in dfs.items():
   df = {}
   dfs[name] = df
```

Comment: `df` is just a local variable here.  Assigning a new value to it affects nothing other than the variable.

Comment: You're reassigning to the loop variable, that's nothing to do with the dictionary.

Comment: Compulsory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: "When I modify each df in the for loop, why isn't this change updated to the dfs?" You don't mutate anything in your for-loop. You assign an empty dict to the variable `df`. Why would that affect `dfs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df` is a local variable defined each time for loop runs. So, it would behave like a new variable, and assigning a new value would not change the source (`dfs`). What you need is exactly as your second cell, but to have a better understanding, I have edited it a little bit:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  "a": [420, 380, 390],
  "b": [50, 40, 45]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  "c": [420, 380, 390],
  "d": [50, 40, 45]
})

dfs = {'df1': df1, 'df2':df2}

print('dfs before: ', dfs)
for name, df in dfs.items():
    dfs[name] = {}


print('dfs after: ', dfs)
```

##### Output

```
dfs before:  {'df1':      a   b
0  420  50
1  380  40
2  390  45, 'df2':      c   d
0  420  50
1  380  40
2  390  45}
dfs after:  {'df1': {}, 'df2': {}}
```

Comment: I thought it is modified 'by reference', like a dict variable passed into function. So the  scope is different in the two cases.

Comment: @marlon In python, there is no such concept as *scope* like what we encounter in other programming languages like JS and Java. The thing is, exactly as you said, the for-loop is not defining variables by reference, rather it is defining a new variable each time.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani um, **what**? Python *certainly* has a concept of *scope* just like JS and Java.

Comment: @marlon there is no "modify by reference", that isn't really a term. It sounds like pass by reference, but Python **never** uses pass by reference (which is an evaluation strategy).

Comment: @marlon and note, you don't pass *variables* into fucntions. Again, Python **never** supports call-by-reference semantics, so `def foo(d): d = {}` then `x = {1:1}; foo(x); print(x)` will print `{1: 1}` not `{}`.

Comment: Right idea, but wrong justifications. Re: scopes, you may want to give [scopes and namepsaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) from the Python documentation a read. Python most certainly has statically-determined scope. Also I think "defined" is somewhat misleading in this context. You're not creating a new variable, but rather just  re-binding an existing name. "Assigned" would be clearer

Comment: Also note, in *both* JS and Java it would work **exactly the same way** as Python for this particular thing.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Brian . It is interesting that I have never known about `global` and `nonlocal` and other variable bindings. The link you have provided helped me immensely to re-correct my old beliefs. Thanks again. I wish I could delete my previous comment but since deleting will harm the conversation here, I leave it be:).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the note, Juanpa. What I meant by scope was something like *var*, *let*, and *const* in JS. It was entirely my mistake that I thought there was no such thing in python, and I wish I could delete the comment to avoid any misleading in the future, but it might harm the conversation here. Again, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update`:

```
for name, df in dfs.items():
    # make a copy to keep the reference to dfs
    df1 = df.copy()

    # do stuff here
    df1 = df1 / 2

    # update your original dataframe
    df.update(df1)
```

It works only if your operations are inplace.

Output:

```
>>> dfs
{'df1':        a     b
 0  210.0  25.0
 1  190.0  20.0
 2  195.0  22.5,
 'df2':        c     d
 0  210.0  25.0
 1  190.0  20.0
 2  195.0  22.5}
```